# What is "blameless stool"?

Tags: translation

From S.King "He messed himself like a baby, and like a baby’s his stools were yellow and loose and totally blameless."

I can't find any translation. Is it 'involuntary'?

Comment: Which dictionaries have you checked 'blameless' in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess that "blameless" is synonymous with "involuntary" is correct.  It's clear from the context that the character's loss of bowel control is the natural consequence of an overwhelming experience and is therefore not controllable.  Anyone who has been in combat, for example, would understand the situation.